# Modifying Content-Type in ServerletFilter in java under JBOSS

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jboss, content-type

I'm trying to alter the ServeletResponse's Content type using a ServerletFilter.
I set the related properties in the filters in web.xml and take them and set within the ServerletFilter's `doFilter` method.

Actual requirement is sending the content-type as `text/xml; charset=utf-8`. But when I set it as this it always sends as `text/xml;charset=utf-8`. No Space.
I know that there's no meaning of the space in between them. But I'm dealing with a buggy client who requires this badly.

Then I tried to send some other controlled characters and it worked for STX one (text/xml; charset=utf-8) in **tomcat** (7.0.64) servers.
But it doesn't work for **JBOSS** (version : 4).

Output in **Tomcat** : `text/xml; charset=utf-8`
Output in **JBOSS** : `text/xml;charset=utf-8`

I doubt whether is this an encoding conflict (**ASCII / UTF-8**) between JBOSS and Tomcat?
Can somebody give an idea on this.

**Filter :**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>HeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filters.HeaderFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>content-type</param-name>
        <param-value>text/xml;&#8194;charset=utf-8</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>Content_type</param-name>
        <param-value>text/xml; charset=utf-8</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>rq_content-type</param-name>
        <param-value>text/xml; charset=utf-8</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>Header-X</param-name>
        <param-value>Value-X</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/SiteMinderService</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

**ServeletFilter Code :**

```
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        Enumeration<String> en = httpServletRequest.getHeaderNames();
        while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
            String n = en.nextElement();
            System.out.println("doFilter().Already set > "+n+" : "+httpServletRequest.getHeader(n));
        }

        MutableServeletRequest mutableServeletRequest = new MutableServeletRequest((HttpServletRequest) request);

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> rqCustomHeaderEntry : rqCustomHeaders.entrySet()) {
            mutableServeletRequest.putHeader(rqCustomHeaderEntry.getKey(), rqCustomHeaderEntry.getValue()); 
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> rsCustomHeaderEntry : rsCustomHeaders.entrySet()) {

            String key = rsCustomHeaderEntry.getKey();
            String value = rsCustomHeaderEntry.getValue();

            httpServletResponse.addHeader(key, value);

            if("content-type".equalsIgnoreCase(key)){
                httpServletResponse.setContentType(value);
            }

        }

        chain.doFilter(mutableServeletRequest, new HttpServletResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse) {
            @Override
            public void setContentType(final String type) {
               System.out.println("setContentType().I will not set your content-type ("+type+")!");
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: is your response wrapper working? Did you get `setContentType().I will not set your content-type` in the console? What is exactly your question?